# Find the extrema of $\sin(x)\cos(y)$ with the Hessian

Tags: trigonometry, partial-derivative, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix

I've got the following function: $f(x,y) = \sin(x)\cos(y)$.

I performed the Hessian matrix correctly, with the second derivatives:

\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin(x)\cos(y) & -\cos(x)\sin(y)\\
-\cos(x)\sin(y) & -\sin(x)\cos(y)
\end{bmatrix}

But the trouble comes when I want to find the extrema (critical points and saddle points). By solving $\cos(x)\cos(y) = 0$ and $-\sin(x)\sin(y) = 0$ (the first partial derivatives) I obtain:

> $\cos(x) = 0$ or $\cos(y) = 0$
>
> $\sin(x) = 0$ or $\sin(y) = 0$.

If $\cos(x) = 0$, then $\sin(x) = \pm 1$ and if $\sin(x) = 0$ then $\cos(x) = \pm1$. Well, here I think that we have got just two possibilities:

1. $\cos(x) = \sin(y) = 0$;
2. $\sin(x) = \cos(y) = 0$.

Now, how do I find the extrema?

I mean, with $\cos(x) = \sin(y) = 0$, which is the point $(x, y)$ and how do I substitute it in the Hessian matrix? (The solution says it must a saddle point but I don't get it, why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical points are

- $f_x=\cos x \cos y=0$
- $f_y=-\sin x \sin y=0$

and thus

- $x=k\pi \quad y=\frac{\pi}2+j\pi$
- $y=k\pi \quad x=\frac{\pi}2+j\pi$

the Hessian matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin x \cos y & -\cos x \sin y \\
-\cos x \sin y & -\sin x \cos y 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and for $x=k\pi \quad y=\frac{\pi}2+j\pi$ we obtain

$$H_1=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \quad H_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and for $y=k\pi \quad x=\frac{\pi}2+j\pi$ we obtain

$$H_3=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \quad H_4=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $H_1$,$H_2$ have signature (1,1), $H_3$ have signature (2,0) and $H_4$ have signature (0,2).

Comment: Is $(0,0)$ a critical point to begin with?

Comment: How do you know that we must check (0,0)? ( @egreg is right )

Comment: @egreg ops...of course it is not!

Comment: @alienflow Sorry, of course egreg is right! I've updated the answer, let me know about it.

Comment: Now yes I got it! Just an obs @gimusi you need a - in the matrix last row last column

Comment: @alienflow Oh yes of course! I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Find the extrema of $f(x,y) = \sin(x)\cos(y)$.

$$\begin{cases} f_x=\cos x\cos y=0 \\ f_y=-\sin x\sin y=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow 1)\begin{cases}\cos x=0 \\ \sin y=0\end{cases} \ \ \text{or} \ \ 2)\begin{cases}\cos y=0 \\ \sin x=0\end{cases}.$$
The Hessian is:
$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin x \cos y & -\cos x \sin y \\
-\cos x \sin y & -\sin x \cos y 
\end{bmatrix}\\
H_1=-\sin x\cos y; \ \ \ H_2=\sin^2 x\cos^2y-\cos^2x\sin^2y.$$
For $1)$: 
$$a) \begin{cases}\cos x=0 \\ \sin y=0 \\ \sin x=1 \\ \cos y=1\end{cases} \Rightarrow H_1=-1<0, H_2=1>0 \Rightarrow max; \\ 
b) \begin{cases}\cos x=0 \\ \sin y=0 \\ \sin x=-1 \\ \cos y=1\end{cases} \Rightarrow H_1=1>0, H_2=1>0 \Rightarrow min; \\
c) \begin{cases}\cos x=0 \\ \sin y=0 \\ \sin x=1 \\ \cos y=-1\end{cases} \Rightarrow H_1=1>0, H_2=1>0 \Rightarrow min; \\
d) \begin{cases}\cos x=0 \\ \sin y=0 \\ \sin x=-1 \\ \cos y=-1\end{cases} \Rightarrow H_1=-1<0, H_2=1>0 \Rightarrow max. \\$$
Can you handle $2)$?

Comment: I was just wondering what is H1 and H2?

Comment: it is indicated right after the Hessian: $H_1=-\sin x\cos y$.

Comment: I understand, but why do you split H in H1 and H2? How do you get H2? (It is not the determinant ?? Im just curious bc i have never solved that way)

Comment: $H_1=f_{xx}$. Check here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html

Answer (score 0):

You compute the Hessian wrongly; it is actually
$$
H(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin(x)\cos(y) & -\cos(x)\sin(y)\\
-\cos(x)\sin(y) & -\sin(x)\cos(y)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
At the points where $\cos x=0$ and $\sin y=0$, the determinant of the Hessian is $1$, so these are either maxima or minima (the eigenvalues are either both positive or both negative).

At the points where $\sin x=0$ and $\cos y=0$, the determinant of the Hessian is $-1$, so these are saddle points (one eigenvalue is positive, the other one is negative).

If you limit yourself to $x$ and $y$ in $[0,2\pi)$, which is simpler, the points are
\begin{align}
&(\pi/2,0),\quad
(\pi/2,\pi),\quad
(3\pi/2,0),\quad
(3\pi/2,\pi)\\
&(0,\pi/2),\quad
(\pi,\pi/2),\quad
(0,3\pi/2),\quad
(\pi,3\pi/2)
\end{align}
Can you assign each of these points the property of being maximum, minimum or saddle?

Since the function is periodic of period $2\pi$ in each variable, adding integer multiples of $2\pi$ to the points above will give the whole set.

Comment: You re right, I have copied wrongly the matrix but I ve alreaamdy changed it!